# Error .jar not found using sonarqube community plugin in a kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, plugins, sonarqube

I used a deployment file and the image https://hub.docker.com/layers/mc1arke/sonarqube-with-community-branch-plugin/latest/images/sha256-589471fe60ec565cb517310a3d2602f1ca6c9e92b8cb0c4215109abc06386980?context=explore to publish this plugin in a kubernetes cluster, but my pod returns this:
Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : ./extensions/plugins/sonarqube-community-branch-plugin-1.14.0.jar
Error occurred during initialization of VM

I've already tried to build a customized image where i added a COPY line trying to put this file there. I also can't attach my pod cause this error happens before his full instalation. I've searched a lot and tried changing soma permisions but nothing happened. This error just stays intact